# How to make CMake detect ar and nm if there is no dash after the toolchain prefix?

Tags: cmake, clang, texas-instruments, cmake-modules

I'm working on a CMake toolchain file for the new LLVM/Clang based compiler from Texas Instruments (see [ARM-CGT-CLANG-1](https://www.ti.com/tool/download/ARM-CGT-CLANG-1)).

CMake properly detects that it's a clang based compiler if I simply set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to the correct path of the `tiarmclang` binary.
Unfortunately, I've noticed that it does not set `CMAKE_AR`, `CMAKE_NM`, `CMAKE_READELF` and `CMAKE_STRIP` correctly.

I've went through some of the modules included with CMake, including [CMakeDetermineCCompiler](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake) and [CMakeFindBinUtils](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CMakeFindBinUtils.cmake).
What I get from that, is that *CMakeDetermineCCompiler* determines the `_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` using a regular expression which expects a dash (`-`) in front of `clang` in the name of the compiler.
This `_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` is later on used in *CMakeFindBinUtils* to prefix the names of the tools.

Unfortunately, TI decided to not include a dash in the name, which I think is the root cause of CMake not being able to detect the bin utils.
I tried setting the `_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` from the toolchain file, but this does not work (it is overwritten in the *CMakeDetermineCCompiler* module).

Is there a way to have CMake find the tools automatically, despite the wonky prefix?
Or is setting the variables for each binutil by hand from the toolchain file the only workaround (which I'm doing at the moment)?

Comment: You can use [`variable_watch`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) to hijack the `set(...)` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation, it turns out that setting the correct prefix in the cache will result in the bin utils to be discovered correctly (at least the ones that are included in the TI toolchain):

```
set(_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "tiarm" CACHE INTERNAL "Toolchain prefix" FORCE)
```